# How to add subtext to images in sitefinity gallery?

Tags: razor, sitefinity

I need to add subtext to each image in sitefinity gallery. I've tried putting each image inside a div and group it that way but that messed up gallery formatting completely. I've also tried using spans and with that I only managed to position the text using not so responsive css.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count(); i++)
{
    var item = Model.Items.ElementAt(i);
    var thumbnailViewModel = (ThumbnailViewModel)item;

    var itemIndex = (Model.CurrentPage - 1) * ViewBag.ItemsPerPage + i + 1;
    var detailPageUrl = ViewBag.OpenInSamePage ? HyperLinkHelpers.GetDetailPageUrl(item, ViewBag.DetailsPageId, ViewBag.OpenInSamePage, Model.UrlKeyPrefix, itemIndex) :
        HyperLinkHelpers.GetDetailPageUrl(item, ViewBag.DetailsPageId, ViewBag.OpenInSamePage, Model.UrlKeyPrefix);

    <a class="text-center"
       href="@detailPageUrl"
       title="@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Fields.Description) ? item.Fields.Title : item.Fields.Description)">

        <img class="gallery_images" src="@(thumbnailViewModel.ThumbnailUrl)" alt='@System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(item.Fields.AlternativeText, @"[^\w\d_-]", "")'
             @Html.GetWidthAttributeIfExists(thumbnailViewModel.Width)
             @Html.GetHeightAttributeIfExists(thumbnailViewModel.Height) />


    </a>

  }
```

this is the code that actually populates the gallery. how do I add subtext to each image and keep it actually under the image and with the image?
This is what each image should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB1PS.png

Comment: What image field are you going to display as a text? 
I guess you have put it under the image, but the problem is you need to properly css align it?

Comment: @VeselinVasilev The text field isn't in the code above, I tried adding a span under the `<a>` tag but the span appears next to the image. I did move it under the image using css but it wasn't very responsive(decreasing window size made the text move away from the image). When I tried putting all of the elements inside a div it just moved all the images inside a gallery under eachother not side-by-side. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Which View do you use - ImageGallery, OverlayGallery, ThumbnailStrip?